# Eclipse CDT unresolved string type

Tags: linux, eclipse, string, eclipse-cdt

I have Eclipse CDT 3.7.2 on my Linux 12.04, 32-bit machine up and running. I am getting an error of unresolved string type even though the inclusion exist in my project's header files.

Anyone ran into this problem, please help.

Comment: I did even add using std::string; following some of the solutions around the web. But what I still get unresolved type.

Comment: This is so weird!!! this problem does not exist when I made a Hello world project!